# ant sonar - class not found error

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I'm seeing the following errors when running ant with sonar.  I'm not even using those classes on my code.  ANy ideas?

```
[sonar:sonar] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
[sonar:sonar] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 8
[sonar:sonar] JavaClasspath initialization...
[sonar:sonar] JavaClasspath initialization done: 2603 ms
[sonar:sonar] JavaTestClasspath initialization...
[sonar:sonar] JavaTestClasspath initialization done: 2247 ms
[sonar:sonar] Java Main Files AST scan...
[sonar:sonar] 64 source files to be analyzed
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent.LazyInit
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.j2objc.annotations.RetainedWith
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent.LazyInit
[sonar:sonar] Class not found: com.google.j2objc.annotations.RetainedWith
[sonar:sonar] 21/64 files analyzed, current file: xxxx
[sonar:sonar] 63/64 files analyzed, current file: xxxx
[sonar:sonar] Java Main Files AST scan done: 21433 ms
[sonar:sonar] 64/64 source files have been analyzed
[sonar:sonar] Java bytecode scan...
[sonar:sonar] Java bytecode scan done: 464 ms
[sonar:sonar] Java Test Files AST scan...
[sonar:sonar] 7 source files to be analyzed
[sonar:sonar] Java Test Files AST scan done: 1689 ms
[sonar:sonar] 7/7 source files have been analyzed
[sonar:sonar] Package design analysis...
[sonar:sonar] Package design analysis done: 26 ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=29620ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor Lines Sensor
[sonar:sonar] Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=13ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor CoberturaSensor
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This debug information is likely related to n-th level dependencies. This is info-only and printed as a warning that the analysis might not be as detailed as possible because those binaries weren't available to factor in to it.